# Glide Module Loading url Images In Custom Sizes with paths and any uri handling

Tags: android, android-glide

I have followed this [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-optimizing-by-loading-images-in-custom-sizes) where it is declared a custom Glide Module to load different image sizes from server depending on the `ImageView` size. I have also taken a look to [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Downloading-custom-sizes-with-Glide) Glide wiki which explains the same.

But the implementation on the tutorial and the Glide wiki only works if the String you send to the Custom Module is a http/https url. How can I modify this Custom Module or create a new one in order to handle all other types (String, Uri, int, etc as Glide.load() does) and keep the functionality presented in the tutorial?

Comment: why not use `.override(width,height)` method in glide ?  see [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1919) for explanation

Comment: Override resizes the image. When possible, I want to request from server the exact imageView size. So image resize is not done. That's the best performance and optimization.

Comment: @DamiaFuentes if API doesn't imply it, you cannot request images in different sizes.

Comment: @Alexey My server API has that functionality

Comment: @AbhishekSingh - Please look to the hyperlinks and you will understand my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of registering the new `ModelLoader` with `append()`, which handle new types of data, register it using `prepend()`, which handle subsets of existing data where you do want to fall back to Glide’s default behavior if your ModelLoader fails. So instead of creating the new `Glide`'s input data (in the tutorial named as `CustomImageSizeModelFutureStudio`), tell Glide, in the case of a `String`, to check if you want to modify the `String` and create your url or let `Glide` do his work without modifying the `String`. Here is my implementation in `Kotlin`. In this case, if your input is "https://...." it will request your custom url. If your input is "content://..." your `ModelLoader` will fail because of the `handles()` method and `Glide` will do it's work.

The implementation of `AppGlideModule`:

```
@GlideModule
class MyGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context?, glide: Glide?, registry: Registry?) {
        registry?.prepend(String::class.java, InputStream::class.java, CustomImageSizeUrlLoaderFactory())
    }
}
```

The implementation of `ModelLoaderFactory`:

```
class CustomImageSizeUrlLoaderFactory : ModelLoaderFactory<String, InputStream> {
    private val modelCache = ModelCache<String, GlideUrl>(500)

    override fun build(multiFactory: MultiModelLoaderFactory): ModelLoader<String, InputStream> {
        val modelLoader = multiFactory.build(GlideUrl::class.java, InputStream::class.java)
        return CustomImageSizeUrlLoader(modelLoader, modelCache)
    }

    override fun teardown() {

    }
}
```

The implementation of `BaseGlideUrlLoader`:

```
class CustomImageSizeUrlLoader(concreteLoader: ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream>, modelCache: ModelCache<String, GlideUrl>?) : BaseGlideUrlLoader<String>(concreteLoader, modelCache) {
    override fun getUrl(baseImageUrl: String, width: Int, height: Int, options: Options?): String {
        return  baseImageUrl + "?w=" + width + "&h=" + height;
    }

    override fun handles(model: String): Boolean {
        return baseImageUrl.startsWith("http://")
                || baseImageUrl.startsWith("https://")
    }
}
```

And call your Glide as you will normally do, not as the tutorial does.

Answer (score -2):

To load image in different sizes, you can use glide's default method `override`
Check below code snippet for load image from different sizes.

```
GlideApp  
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .override(customwidth, customheight) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). resize does not respect aspect ratio
    .into(imageViewResize);
```

If you want to maintain aspect ratio as well, you can use `fitCenter()` or `centerCrop()`.